# Типичная ситуация с версиями jquery...

Tags: jquery, плагин

Уверен, что сейчас в меня полетят камни, ну да ладно.
Свежескачанный и настроенный скрипт стилизации select'a, оказался работоспособным с jquery 1.7.1, но ругается на мою 1.9.0.. Как и половина скриптов в интернете.. Может есть какая-нибудь заплатка, чтобы он заработал? Если что, скрипт называется jQueryCoreUISelect, и плюётся он ошибкой

> Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined

на вот эту строчку

```
$.browser.mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

UPD: Ребята, а вы обращаете внимания, на то, **что именно** у вас спрашивают? Я спросил не почему так, я знаю почему, я спросил про заплатку для этого.

Comment: Данное расширение устарело начиная с 1.9. Подробности в официальной документации:  
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

Comment: Да я в курсе( жалко что не в курсе разработчики jQueryCoreUISelect(

Comment: @Dazar отпишитесь им.

Comment: @lampa, кстати, а почему бы и нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin.

Comment: спасибки, то, что надо